# Html to Pdf conversion issue

Tags: html

Actually I'm A beginner and I'm trying to build a website as given same to same in a particular pdf and I thought Ok lets see how mine looks when converted to pdf so I did and saw that Background images are small and Fonts are out of Background
Does anybody know how to solve this?????

Comment: Google "html CSS for print"

Comment: Why Google when we know their [URL](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: One way to convert HTML to PDF is using the DocumentConverter class from the LEADTOOLS toolkit. (Disclaimer: I am a developer for the vendor). You can see an overview on how to do this using this class [here](https://www.leadtools.com/blog/document-imaging/document-converter/convert-html-pdf-vb-java/). If this is a good option for you and you wish to give this a try, you can download a free evaluation from [here](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads).